# LaCie 2big network – replaced both disks, now it won't boot

Tags: networking, hard-drive, raid

I had to replace both disks in my LaCie 2big due to a disk failure, but now I cannot get it working again.

The 2big will not show up in LaCie network assistant or get access through its IP address. I have tried to set it back to factory settings, but that did not work either. The 2big was set up in RAID so that if one disk should fail, data would still be intact.

All data that was on those disks has been backed up so I am not concerned for data loss.

- Operating System: OSX 10.13 High Sierra
- 2big is connected to the network

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Lacie stores the boot system in the first system partition within the RAID itself, if you replace both at the same time the boot is lost. Try the reset sequence, but I don't know if that will restore the boot loadeer.

http://knowledge.lacie.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/006536en?language=en-us

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the reset sequence only reset some config files...

Without any system on any HDD, there is nothing to reset...

From LaCie support, buying an official HDD replacement hardware while bring you the system as well.